# Poynting vectors of perpendicular intersecting waves

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, interference, poynting-vector

Let us assume that wave $E_a(x,t)=Ae^{i(kx-wt)}$ is propagating along the $x$-axis and that wave $E_b(y,t)=Be^{i(ky-wt)}$ is propagating along the $y$-axis. The magnitude of the Poynting vector $\mathbf{P}_a$ (related to $E_a$) in the $x$-direction should be proportional to $A^2$ and the magnitude of the Poynting vector $\mathbf{P}_b$ (related to $E_b$) in the $y$-direction should be proportional to $B^2$.

Assuming $E_a$ and $E_b$ intersect vertically at the origin then the cross product $\mathbf{P}_a \times \mathbf{P}_b$ should give a vector in the $z$-direction with a magnitude proportional to $A^2 B^2$.

1. If this is correct, what is the physical meaning of this $z$-direction vector? Is it another Poynting vector created by the intersection of $E_a$ and $E_b$?
2. If it is a Poynting vector, is its magnitude really proportional to $A^2 B^2$ and not to $(Ae^{i(kx-wt)}+Be^{i(ky-wt)})^2$? Are there no interference effects?

Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

(1) There is no physical meaning to it, because there is no reasonable physical situation where you would take the cross product of two different Poynting vectors for different electric fields.

The *dot* product might have an interpretation, something about how
$$(E_1 \times B_1)\cdot(E_2 \times B_2) = (E_1\cdot E_2)(B_1\cdot B_2)-(E_1\cdot B_2)(E_2\cdot B_1),$$
but even that seems dubious without some sort of Hodge rotation causing this dot product between the electric fields of one and the magnetic fields of the other on the right.

But I don't see any route to any sort of interesting result using cross product here.

(2) Whether interference occurs in the superposition of $E_1 + E_2$, $B_1 + B_2$ is unspecified. If they are both z-polarized then it does. If either one is not then it doesn't.

Comment: Thank for the response. The two vertically intersecting waves should also produce a poynting vector in the z-direction. what would be the magnitude of that poynting vector? is it proportional to AB or to (A^2)(B^2)?

Comment: It is a sum of terms each proportional to one of those three, as it must be.

Comment: do you mean that the magnitude in the z-direction should be proportional to (A^2)(B^2)?